# Error with dbConnect to Snowflake via Rscript (but not R Studio)

Tags: r, networking, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully connected/queried Snowflake from R Studio using an ODBC driver. When I try the code in Rgui.exe, it also works. However, in Rterm (or calling rScript from a batch script), it does not. Rterm returns the following error:

```
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

My R code is:

```
library(ROracle)
library(methods)

username <- keyring::key_list("blake-snowflake")[1,2]
password <- keyring::key_get("blake-snowflake", keyring::key_list("my-snowflake")[1,2])

### connect to EDW
con_snowflake <- dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(), 
  "EDW_sample", 
  uid=username, 
  pwd=password)
```

Comment: Have you verified that `keyring::key_get` works in `Rterm`? (I don't know for certain, just checking loose ends ...)

Comment: Yes, it works in Rterm

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using ODBC to JDBC.

```r
library(RJDBC)

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", classPath = "..\\java\\snowflake-jdbc-3.7.2.jar") 

con_snowflake <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://xxx.snowflakecomputing.com/", keyring::key_list("my-snowflake")[1,2], keyring::key_get("my-snowflake", keyring::key_list("my-snowflake")[1,2]), db="db_name", schema="schema_name")

### read in data
query = readr::read_file("...\\query.sql")
df <- ROracle::dbGetQuery(con_snowflake, query)
```